# Controlling esp2886 via bluetooth... help!

Tags: bluetooth, esp8266, robotics

I am trying to control my esp2866 via bluetooth so I bought a DSD TECH SH-M08 Bluetooth 4.0 BLE Module. In a tutorial I saw they paired it to the computer and then under 'More Bluetooth Options', in the COM Ports tab it shows up and you simply take the COM port it's connected to and put it into your code.

For some reason though, the module doesn't show up in the COM Ports tab. It does however show up in device manager.

Another way of connecting it is via the AT Command line however I don't fully understand how to do this.

I also have an HC-05 but it runs on 2.0 BLE can I connect this to my computer? My computer doesn't seem to be able to detect it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: would be far simpler to just get an esp32 than mess around with semi-compatible modules.

Comment: Ah maybe but I have already soldered everything into place and I finally managed to get this board to work right.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you, since you just reported that something didn't work, but you didn't show how the devices are interconnected. There could be a lot of things that could fail. The answer from @ThatKeffordGuy below may point a way. How do you know that ESP8266 is doing serial communication? Did you test this module with a wired serial connection? I would suggest that you **first** get your device working, connected to the computer with an USB-serial adapter in a wired connection. Only after that, you would begin trying to replace the USB adapter with the BT adapter.

Comment: It all works via wired connection and I've built an interface through which I can control the robot with my computer. Now I'm jus trying to go wireless.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment but I don't have the rep so I'll have to leave an answer instead.
It would probably be easiest to begin with talking to the module via a terminal and sending it AT commands. Then you can type commands freely and see the responses immediately, without having to write code to send and receive the messages.

You'll need an FTDI cable which you plug into your PC, this will appear as a COM port which you can select in a terminal program such as termite or tera term.

Looking at the pinout of that module, you'll need an FTDI cable with separate connectors like [this](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1U6BYJVXXXXXlapXXq6xXFXXX4/FT232-Brush-line-USB-To-TTL-Serial-Cable-Line-Electric-Adapter-FTDI-Chipset-Computer-FT232RL.jpg), as the pinout does not match the standard FTDI pinout. Connect Vcc, Tx, Rx and Gnd.

Start by powering up the module and watching for a boot message. If it appears scrambled, your baud rate may be wrong.

Get the [datasheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8X0PfU0omF3Nm1sTVBRZ0Z6dms/view) and try typing commands like AT+ADDR?
See what you get back.

It looks like quite an awkward module to learn on, with not great documentation. You may be better getting something like [this](https://www.silabs.com/development-tools/wireless/bluetooth/bgx220p-bluetooth-xpress-starter-kit) which you can plug a USB cable into and also has great documentation for the [hardware](https://www.silabs.com/development-tools/wireless/bluetooth/bgx220p-bluetooth-xpress-starter-kit) and the [API](https://docs.silabs.com/gecko-os/1/bgx/latest/commands).

Also did you mean ESP8266?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go, and yes I meant ESP8266.

Comment: No problem. I think once you try some commands and see the responses coming back things will suddenly click into place for you. It's the nice part about the BT modules that use human readable AT commands :)